# 2008 Chevy cobalt starting problems

Tags: battery, chevrolet, alternator, cobalt

So the car was having trouble starting for the longest time. Put the key in the ignition turn and get a single click with no start. After a few tries it usually starts right up. Car slowly died while driving a few weeks ago all the lights on the dash went off and the car slowly shuddered and died. thought it was just the battery but the road side assistance guy said it was the alternator. So I got both the battery and the alternator replaced last week and the car worked like a dream for about 3 days not click everything good.

Then it started up with the click no start again. Sometimes it'd start right up other times it would take anywhere from 3-20 tries to start. Yesterday the car died on me again. dash went out power steering went out and nothin. i managed to get it started again to slug my way out but it was still having trouble.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Might want to voltage drop the starter b+ terminal, when you're trying to crank the engine. Check your battery terminal connections and battery charge as well.

Comment: Sounds like it was never the alternator, something else is causing a major battery draw, turn off the car and do an amp draw on all of the fuses

Comment: Check out https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1z7tbMJK5P8

Answer (score 1):

Kind of sounds like a possible ignition switch. Go onto Chevy website. Check for recalls.

Comment: Actually just got that recall done by chevy. ignition lock cylinder and switch.

Comment: Did the problem start after that? Or has it been going on for a while?

Comment: the clicking problem started before the recall. the car stopping started after the recall.